# Swift + UIView: How to change y coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView called `descriptionView` and I want to hide it initially when the screen first loads by offsetting the y coordinate to be the screen size + the height of `descriptionView` itself:

[image]

However, in my controller, none of my frame changes do anything:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
//    descriptionView.frame.origin.y =  self.view.frame.height
//    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
//      self.descriptionView.frame.origin.y =  self.view.frame.height
//      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
//    })
//    
    print("xxx")
    descriptionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height, self.view.frame.width, 66)
//    descriptionView.frame = CGRectOffset(descriptionView.frame, 0, descriptionView.frame.height)
  }
```

No matter what I do it seems fixed at that visible position like in my storyboard. Can someone help?

Comment: Try updating the frame in `viewDidAppear:`, just want to know if the constraints are holding it.

Comment: @Firo yeh it finally made it disappear after moving the stuff to `viewDidAppear`. but is that safe to put it in there? doesn't that mean the changes will be made after the view is visible ?

Comment: Either change the constraint (assuming your using layout constraints), or change it's hidden property (as an alternative).

Comment: i want to eventually slide it up into the view though. if i hide it it won't animate properly i think

Comment: @Edmund, see my answer about `viewDidLoad`. Instead of using `viewDidAppear:` you should probably use `viewWillAppear:`. I just generally use `viewDidAppear:` for easy testing, that's all.

Comment: @Firo using viewWillAppear doesn't seem to work. only viewDidAppear has worked so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `IB` you are using `NSAutoLayout`, so you either need to manipulate the constraints, or tell the view to translate the mask to constraints.

If you want to set the frame directly then you will want to do this:

```
descriptionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
descriptionView.frame = CGRectMake(...)
```

Otherwise you can create `IBOutlets` to the `height` and `width` constraint from IB and update those:

```
self.descriptionViewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.width
```

Additionally, I would recommend doing frame manipulations inside of `viewWillAppear:` rather than `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` does not strictly guarantee final position.

Comment: @Firok will do. but one thing is that if the view reappears, if the `descriptionView` has been slided up through an interaction from before, i want it to stay visible and not be hidden. is the only way of doing that by having a local `descriptionViewVisible : boolean` and not change the frame if `descriptionViewVisible == true`?

Comment: i want it to be offscreen at first, and when the user taps on another view element, the `descriptionView` should slide up. that's what i mean by "hidden"

Comment: @Edmund, I would just have the view hidden. When the user presses the button THEN set the initial (offscreen frame), and set `hidden = false`. Then start the animation. I would NOT setup the view ahead of time. Does that make sense?

Comment: really? ok that's fine with me, wasn't really sure the convention is for this kind of stuff. thanks!!!

Comment: In fact, if you could even just add the view programmatically when you need it. But yeah, generally you just set things up when they are needed and if it is not immediately visible, don't bother with it until need be. Hope it all works out for ya!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the frame or `descriptionView`, edit its height constraint.

First, create an `NSLayoutConstraint` from this constraint by cmd-dragging the height constraint from the Interface Builder to your class (like you do for any UI object).

Then you can set the `constant` property of this constraint to 0.

---

(Yes, `constant` is declared as a `var`property...)

Comment: ooo what does the constant property do? so you want me to set the height to 0? when i animate it back into the view (i'm guessing by setting the height to a number), won't it look weird?

Comment: The animation will look like an  "unshrink" of the view. If you want to have the aniamtion to look like a slide, you can use `NSLayoutConstraint` too, but with an other constraint : the one between the bottom of your `descriptionView` and its superview. If you set it to '-descriptionView.frame.height' and animate it later to 0, then you will have your slide effect :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using constraints, chaging the frame view `myView.frame` property will not affect on view actual position and size. Instead of this make constraint outlet and change it in your code, it will look like this:

```
descriptionView.heightConstraint.constant = 100
```

Also, if you want to hide something, you can use property `myView.hidden = true`, or `myView.alpha = 0`;